# Сбрасывание данных на диск

Tags: c++, ос, запись

В какой момент происходит фактическая запись информации на диск?

Есть, к примеру следующий код:

```
std::ofstream file("somefile");
file << "Hello, world!\n";
std::flush(file);
```

Если сразу после выполнения строки `std::flush(file)` я вырубаю электричество, то каковы шансы при его включении увидеть в файле `Hello, World!`? Если шанс не 100%, то как его довести до желаемого гарантийного результата? Есть ли у ОС (Linux/Windows) какие-то способы убедиться, что информация на диск занеслась?
Как такая ситуация обрабатывается в базах данных при транзакциях?

---

UPD: Запишется ли строка в файл, если программа упадет сразу после `std::flush(file)`?

Comment: Вот, например, делаю я какую-то запись в БД транзакционно. Мне БД должна же вернуть, что транзакция успешно закоммичена. Для этого БД должна знать в какой момент транзакция записана на диск / в журнал / лог, чтобы потом можно было по этим данным восстановиться. А про бесперебойники - вопрос больше не в них, а в теоретической ситуации выхода из строя компа с системой так, что диск останется жить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

За исключением случая, когда файл был открыт с флагом `O_SYNC` системного вызова [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) (почитать о всех его флагах будет, вероятно, в любом случае полезно),    `fflush()`  не обеспечивает желаемый вами функционал.
Эта функция перемещает данные из буфера, связанного с файлом в пространстве пользователя, в буферный кэш в пространстве ядра.

Для принудительной синхронизации с устройством при работе с `FILE *` после `fflush` надо выполнить системный вызов [fsync](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) (например, `fflush(file), fsync(fileno(file));`) , который синхронно запишет данные файла (и его метаинформацию) на устройство, обеспечивая также выталкивание кэша устройства, если он существует.

> fsync() transfers ("flushes") all modified in-core data of (i.e.,
>   modified buffer cache pages for) the file referred to by the file
>   descriptor fd to the disk device (or other permanent storage device)
>   so that all changed information can be retrieved even after the system
>   crashed or was rebooted. This includes writing through or flushing a
>   disk cache if present. The call blocks until the device reports that
>   the transfer has completed. It also flushes metadata information
>   associated with the file (see stat(2)).

Однако, обратите внимание на следующий текст в руководстве (man-e)

> Calling fsync() does not necessarily ensure that the entry in the
>   directory containing the file has also reached disk. For that an
>   explicit fsync() on a file descriptor for the directory is also
>   needed.

что может создать проблемы для новых файлов.